# Is there any way to let sympy simplify root(-1, 3) to -1?

Tags: python, sympy

```
root(-1, 3).simplify()
(-1)**(1/3)//Output
```

This is not what I want, any way to simplify this to -1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
real_root(-1, 3)
```

It's referred to in the doc string of the root function too.

The reason is simple: sympy, like many symbolic algebra systems, takes the complex plane into account when calculating "the root". There are 3 complex numbers that, when raised to the power of 3, result in -1. If you're just interested in the real-valued root, be as explicit as you can.